# Google Translate API and Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I wonder if someone could help here.
I can successfully display the translation into the console log, but can't manage to get it into a variable.

Code is:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');
// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = '';
// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({
  projectId: projectId,
});

function translateTo(textToTranslate,target){
    translate
        .translate(textToTranslate, target)
        .then(results => {
            var translation = results[0];
            console.log(`Text: ${textToTranslate}`);
            console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
}

var txtTranslated = translateTo(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript,'fr')
console.log('Txt Translated: ' + txtTranslated)
```

txtTranslated is always empty :-(

Not sure if it helps or not but the function translateTo() is called within a class

Thank you

Comment: Can you expand on your question please?

You are saying that txtTranslated will show up in the `console.log()` right? So what do you mean by you can't get it in a variable?

Comment: console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`); Will display the text translated fine. BUT outside the function, I can't get the translation. This call the function var txtTranslated = translateTo(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript,'fr') and txtTranslated is empty so console.log('Txt Translated: ' + txtTranslated) displays nothing

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the problem is that the function `translateTo` is not actually returning anything. Return the translation and it will be stored in `txtTranslated`.

```
     function translateTo(textToTranslate, target) {
       // ceate a new var to store the result
       var translation = null;
       translate
         .translate(textToTranslate, target)
         .then(results => {
           translation = results[0];
           return translation;
         })
         .catch(err => {
           console.error('ERROR:', err);
         });
       // this should now the translation:
       console.log(translation)
       return translation;
     }

     var txtTranslated = translateTo(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript, 'fr')
     console.log('Txt Translated: ' + txtTranslated)
```

If the console.log before the return is null,then the problem is Async - as in we are not waiting for the translate response before returning the translation in the function.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried using returned. But it doesn't seem to pass the content of the variable back. I've got: Txt Translated: undefined

Comment: please take a look at my edit and let me know what happens

Comment: Thank you for the help Harmonic. You are correct. It's because it's async (node.js is async which I didn't know).

Answer (score 0):

```
sendTranscription(data){
  // use .then() to wait for the promise to resolve before continuing
  this.translateTo(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript,'fr').then(function(txtTranslated) {
 console.log('Txt Translated: ' + txtTranslated)
  var response = {
    text: data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript,
    languageCode: this.request.config.languageCode,
    user: this.user,
    textTranslated: txtTranslated
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    clients[i].send(JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
}.bind(this));
}

// Translate
translateTo(textToTranslate,target){
  // Return here to return the promise
  return translate
      .translate(textToTranslate, target)
      .then(results => {
        var translation = results[0];
        console.log('Text to translate :' + textToTranslate);
        console.log('Translation: ' + translation);
        return translation;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
}
```